# Is it moral to kill a baby?

Tags: ethics

Assuming that heaven exists and that the death of a baby automatically gets him/her to heaven, is it moral to kill your own baby?

Comment: If this is a serious question, then you need your head examined. If this is not a serious question, then you should be ashamed of posting it here.

Comment: My question is in no way claiming that it is moral to kill a baby. I simply want to know reasons for being it immoral. I see that even in a Utilitarianism view point, killing the baby would be immoral, but there is some logic. Killing the baby ensures that the baby will have eternal happiness. The baby may not deserve eternal happiness, but I would say that no one deserves eternal suffering(assuming there is a hell).

Comment: No; you've just invented a rule system that allows you to justify your conclusion.

Comment: It's the logical conclusion, really.  People will always try to game the system.

Comment: If we follow that logic to its conclusion, then it follows that the most efficient way to accumulate moral points is to produce as many baby as possible and then kill them as soon as possible. I don't know about you, but I don't think I would want to live in a world where systematic, mass baby killing is considered moral. Also, since the believe in heaven often goes hand in hand with against abortion, I should note that if one believe that babies automatically goes to heaven, then they should have nothing against abortion.

Comment: Just because you don't like the conclusion doesn't make the logic invalid.

Comment: Mill did indeed argue in _Utilitarianism_ that babies were in a lesser position morally to some more intelligent pets, and that it was therefore as least as acceptable to put a baby down as put a dog down. He did not admit the existence of immortal souls.

Comment: Theology should **never** be involved in a serious moral debate.

Answer (score 1):

Academic philosophy is open to discussing all sorts of questions. Your own question is of the form `if X, is Y acceptable`. However, this `X` seems relevant only for theologians, generally not for philosophers. I'll cite just two of the many cases that discuss the `Y`.

### [Should the baby live?: the problem of handicapped infants](http://www.law2.byu.edu/lawreview/archives/1991/1/bar.pdf)

> There is a limit to the burden of dependence which any community can carry. The amount needed to care for one patient... could be used save the lives of scores of children suffering from malnutrition in less well-developed countries.

### [After-birth abortion: why should the baby live?](http://jme.bmj.com/content/early/2012/04/12/medethics-2011-100411.short)

> Abortion is largely accepted even for reasons that do not have anything to do with the fetus' health. By showing that (1) both fetuses and newborns do not have the same moral status as actual persons, (2) the fact that both are potential persons is morally irrelevant and (3) adoption is not always in the best interest of actual people, the authors argue that what we call ‘after-birth abortion’ (killing a newborn) should be permissible in all the cases where abortion is, including cases where the newborn is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Morality is nonsense, and is the source of many confusion when regarded as guidance.

If the baby's life is one of untold misery, it is humane to terminate its life as soon as possible.

Comment: Is "humane" moral? Why change predicates?

Comment: There is no moral in my system. This is a poorly asked question. Maybe I shouldn't answer it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on relations between the agent who is facing this possibility and her God who has managed such a situation. 
If she thinks that that God is an ultimate source of moral law - why be bothered with such a question? Just do what he commands and that's all. Once in the history Abraham had been ready to do this in complete confidence in God.

However, if this issue seems to be doubtful (and the question implies such doubts), it signifies that the God is not considered as a source of morality. The agent who is deciding - to kill or not to kill a baby - does not think that it would be comfortable in heavens knowing at the same time that people blame her (and majority of them will blame, I guess) .

I think that this agent should decide for herself, does she definetly put her confidence in God and not think from now and forever about opinion of men, or she accepts that they are right blaming the killer and forgets for herself such a way to heavens. This is a question of personal choice; she cannot readdress to anybody else.

Kierkegaard had wrote an excellent book - *Fear and Trembling* - where he argues that the situation of Abraham transcends ethics.

Comment: You're misreading de Silentio in your last paragraph and don't seem to grasp that even if God is the source of ethics, he may not have answered every question in such a way as to be definitive.

Comment: @virmaior I am quite puzzled by your remark – what is wrong? Is it about transcending? - I quote this "_The paradox of faith is this, that the individual is higher than the universal, that the individual... determines his relation to the universal by his relation to the absolute, not his relation to the absolute by his relation to the universal._"
It is difficult to see, at list for me, how God could be not definitive and should count the time and look at what happens as if he faces the time that has a power independent on him. If he hides his answers, people should answer in a definite way.

Comment: On the normal interpretation of de Silentio, there's "ethics" and there's ethics. Where the thing that is overcome is the mistaken Danish Hegelian idea of ethics. I don't know what the sentences after your quote mean. So that's half of my comment.

Comment: I'll expand on my previous remark for the other half. The "Just do what he commands and that's all" is insufficient because God does not necessarily supply a command for every situation. So there's still some leaving down principles or something and leaving details to others OR details that are never accounted for.